# catkin_make error in ROS Indigo

Tags: slam, navigation, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone help me in this regard? Trying to run rgbdslam_v2 on ros idigo, Ubuntu version 14.

```
Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui_b
Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui_f
Built target _rgbdslam_generate_messages_check_deps_rgbdslam_ros_ui_s
[  9%] [ 17%] [ 25%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_py
Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_lisp
Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_cpp
[ 25%] [ 25%] Built target rgbdslam_gencpp
Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libcxsparse.so.2.2.3', needed by `/home/zarneel/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [rgbdslam_v2-hydro/CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207996/catkin_make-error-in-ros-indigo/) by [Zari](https://answers.ros.org/users/22203/zari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-04-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just copy paste one answer from stackoverflow. Cannot find the original link.

I've changed the line in the src/rgbdslam_v2/CMakeLists.txt to the following:

SET(LIBS_LINK GL GLU cholmod /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcxsparse.so.3.1.2
#/usr/lib/libcxsparse.so.2.2.3
${G2O_LIBRARIES} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
And the package compiled. I guess author haven't made a proper cmake search module for it just yet.

The version of libcxsparse on my 14.04 machine is 3.1.2, and it is in folder /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, change the path and it will compile.

---

Originally posted by [BattleField](https://answers.ros.org/users/22522/battlefield/) with karma: 16 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also use cxsparse and avoid the full path, it will work for the current version of that lib installed on the system. It worked for me, 14.04 and Indigo.

```
 SET(LIBS_LINK GL GLU cholmod cxsparse ${G2O_LIBRARIES} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

---

Originally posted by [JFelip](https://answers.ros.org/users/22952/jfelip/) with karma: 11 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dinl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23729/dinl/) on 2015-12-16**:
Thank you, that woks!